# why resource(ex. hello.jpg) access in domain name not work, but ip adress does

Tags: dns, resources

I can access resource in my nodejs server resource folder using ip address.
But, I can not access resource when using domain name...

ex) https://148.xxx.xxx.xxx/hello.jpg => work!
    https://myapp/hello.jpg => 404 error...

Why? is it DNS problem?

Comment: If you try to `ping` the host `myapp`, what do you get then? Have you created an alias (for example in your local `hosts` file) for the `myapp` host?

Comment: `ping` isn't work. I add `app.use(express.static('upload'));` in nodejs, so I can access resource files using ip address, but domain name doen't work..

Comment: aha..now I understand alias..I have not alias in my hosts..